# how to display users when we search for a particular node in the exposed filter in views drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-nodes

I have a view, where user searches for a particular node, and i want it to display the user who created that node.

I have created a view and used exposed filter to list all the nodes in autocomplete, but when i search a particular node, it is displaying a error as 
"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

I am not going anywhere with this, kindly give some suggestions

Thank you.

Comment: what are all the view settings? are you getting the error when you type in the exposed filter, does it expose the node id / node title / user id?

Comment: yes, when i type in the exposed filter i get the error.